# Kate's "open file" in Ubuntu doesn't show all files

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, kate

When I go to open a file from Kate (in Ubuntu), it doesn't show me all the files in the current directory.

What's more, it shows me some files that aren't in the current directory.

Only when I select the drop down menu beside name do I get what seems to be a complete list, and the files (mentioned above) that aren't in the current directory, are at the top of the list, but given without their full paths (all the files in the current directory are listed with their full paths).

This isn't a serious problem, but it's annoying, and seems to make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Gnome or KDE?

In KDE there's a button in the right corner (after clicking on "Open" in Kate), if you click on it there're several options in order to show the files.

Comment: um..  unity?  .. and "the button in the right corner", the thing with the wrench?  it has an option to show hidden files, but that doesn't show the ones in the drop-down list (and the drop down list doesn't show the ones it shows)

Comment: It all sounds very weird, I suggest reinstalling Kate.

Comment: I installed it through the software center, from the repositories..

Comment: Ubuntu uses its own version and patches, and sometimes KDE programs wont run right on another Desktop Environment. Try installing it from source.

Comment: ok. unfortunately (fortunately?), I'm not frustrated enough yet to do that yet.  I have other fish to fry.  I'll try it later and let you know how it worked. -thank's.

Comment: I understand, np.

Comment: haven't checked this yet, but I'll accept it as thank's for your feedback.

Comment: ok, apparently don't need to use the tag @user247346 just here..

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the fix. In Kate, when you are at the Open File dialog window, seeing your visible files and wishing for the hidden ones to appear, you can right-click in the pane (the one that is listing the files) and select "Show Hidden Files."

When you close the Open File dialog window and re-open it, your setting is remembered. When you quit and restart Kate, your settings are still remembered.

My system is Fedora 37 beta, Mate-Compiz spin. Kate version 22.08.1.